# Problema con los headers NODEJS Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, express, jwt

Buen día , tengo un problema . estoy haciendo un middleware que valide un jwt , al declarar el header parece que primero ejecuta la función a verificar y después declara el header , pero esto solo sucede aveces, y me aparece este error en el postman y el error en la consola como aparece en la la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi pregunta es como podría hacer para que siempre se ejecute la declaración del header sin que la función se ejecute primero ya intente de muchas formas en el código y no eh encontrado solución

este es el codigo del middleware

```
  const { request, response } = require('express');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const validarJWT = (req = request, res = response, next) => {
    
        const token = req.header('x-token');
    
        try {
    
            if (!token) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    msg: 'No hay token en la peticion'
                });
            } else {
                jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRETORPRIVATEKEY)
            }
    
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(401).json({
                msg: 'token no valido'
            })
        }
        next();
    }
    module.exports = {
        validarJWT
    }
```

y este el codigo de mis rutas

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');

const { usuariosGet, usuariosPost, usuariosPut, usuariosDelete, usuariosPatch } = require('../controllers/usuarios');
const { esRoleValido, emailExiste, existeUsuarioPorId } = require('../helpers/db-validators');
const { validarCampos } = require('../middlewares/validar-campos');
const Role = require('../models/role');
const { validarJWT} = require('../middlewares/validar-jwt');
const router = Router();
router.get('/', usuariosGet);
router.post('/', [
   check('correo','el correo no es valido').isEmail(),
   check('password','el pasword es incorrecto mas de 6 letras').isLength({min:6}),
   check('nombre','el nombre es obligatorio').not().isEmpty(),
   check('rol').custom((rol)=>esRoleValido(rol)),//esRoleValido tambien solo puede referenciar asi
   check('correo').custom((correo)=>emailExiste(correo)),
  // check('rol','No es un rol valido').isIn(['ADMIN_ROLE','USER_ROLE']),
   validarCampos
], usuariosPost);
router.put('/:id',[
   check('id','No es un ID valido').isMongoId(),
   check('id').custom((id)=>existeUsuarioPorId(id)),
   check('rol').custom((rol)=>esRoleValido(rol)),
   validarCampos
], usuariosPut);
router.delete('/:id', [
   validarJWT,
   check('id','No es un ID valido').isMongoId(),
   check('id').custom((id)=>existeUsuarioPorId(id)),
   validarCampos
],usuariosDelete);
router.patch('/', usuariosPatch);
module.exports = router
```

Comment: En el código de tu función middleware tienes 2 llamados a la función `next()`, esto podría estar provocando el problema. Revisa la lógica de tu función, tienes un llamado a `next()` dentro del bloque `try`, luego fuera de todo el `try ... catch` tienes un último llamado a `next()`. Intenta eliminar este último llamado y verifica el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora entiendo por que aveces llamaba y otras  veces no me sirvió mucho